# Backup existing drivers from a live laptop, snapshot the current drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Is there a software which can backup existing drivers from a working laptop with Windows 7 Pro 32 .I'm upgrading to Windows 7 Ultimate on a new HDD on the laptop, but do not want to install drivers from the manufacturer's website after the fresh install. A friend told me that SiSoft has a software, but I have not found one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Driver Max](http://www.innovative-sol.com/drivermax/index.htm)** or **[Double Driver](http://boozet.org/dd.htm)**(freeware) should do the job for you.

Keep **[LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/)** in your bookmarks for nifty/niche tools like these.

Answer (score -1):

You can backup all files in the `%WINDIR%` but the restore won't work because the entries in the registry will be missing.

What you need it a tool that can snapshot Windows and then create a package after the installation with all the changes. After the tool has created the file, you will need to clean it (for example from all the entries which your virus scanner created).

Conclusion: Forget it. Save the driver installation files on an external hard disk and use them to install the drivers again.